# Elegant syntax for assigning value from possibly null db value

Tags: c#

For some context, the record class SaleAmount property is

```
public decimal? SaleAmount
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Ideally I would go with this

```
record.SaleAmount.Value = 
sql.Reader.IsDBNull(IDX_SALEAMOUNT) ? null : 
    sql.Reader.GetDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT);
```

Alas the compiler and this are not friends because...

*Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'decimal'*

So how would you express this elegantly, and dont play the obvious card like below...

```
if (!sql.Reader.IsDBNull(IDX_SALEAMOUNT))
    record.SaleAmount = sql.Reader.GetDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT);
```

Or is above the best solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using C# 3, I'd actually make this easier for yourself using an extension method:

```
public static decimal? GetNullableDecimal(this DbReader reader, 
    int column)
{
    return reader.IsDBNull(column) ? (decimal?) null : 
        reader.GetDecimal(column);
}
```

Then your application code can just use:

```
record.SaleAmount = sql.Reader.GetNullableDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT);
```

Comment: +1: Clever, readable function. In my opinion, it would even be worth defining such a static helper method in earlier C# versions.

Comment: Introducing static extension method complexity for a trivial problem seems like a bad tradeoff to me

Comment: I hate it that the rich keep getting richer and I really want to give someone other than Skeet the win on this...maybe someone should copy this answer and mod it just a tad so I can give them the check mark!

Comment: As soon as this logic is involved in more than one place, having a method for it will definitely be worth it. The fact that it's an extension method doesn't change much, since that's just syntactic sugar and would very rarely cause any problems.

Comment: @Andomar: Once you've done this once - probably doing it for all the various value types in one go - you're done, and from then on your application code looks cleaner. That's a tradeoff I'll take in a heartbeat. Who wants to see all that cruft in their business logic code?

Comment: @Tony the Pony: You certainly make it sound good.  But I'd be afraid to move away from the well known SqlClient API to the dreaded home baked system library layer.

Comment: @Andomar: But the beauty is these are just utility methods. You're not designing extra class hierarchies etc, just avoiding writing the same thing time and again.

Comment: @Andomar: That's not what extension methods do (although they do act as if they do, I guess)... They simply save you from typing `DbReaderUtility.GetNullableDecimal(reader, IDX_SALEAMOUNT)`. Sure, a person not aware of extension methods might be baffled at first, but such is the case with all that is new and different...

Comment: You guys are probably right.  I'm a grumpy old programmer with a deep distrust of utility functions made in-house.

Comment: This makes me really wish my company would upgrade us to .NET 3.5...on another note, I will always choose to write helper methods like this, saves my fingers the strain later on and it's so much prettier when looking at the main method.

Comment: I do this. +1 for thinking like me!

Answer (score 3):

You could go with:

```
record.SaleAmount = 
    (sql.Reader.IsDBNull(IDX_SALEAMOUNT) ? null : 
     sql.Reader.GetDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT)) as decimal?;
```

You could try another way:

```
// usage: new GenericDataReader(cm.ExecuteReader())
//        ...Get<decimal?>(...);
public class GenericDataReader : IDataReader
{
    // IDataReader implementation
    public T Get<T>(int ordinal)
    {
        if (_dataReader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
            return default(T);
        else
            return (T)_dataReader.GetValue(ordinal);
    }
}
```

More about this approach [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2473902/Generic-data-fetch-with-IDataReader-modified.aspx).

Comment: This is a more "generic" :) approach to the problem, unfortunately this will lead to lot's of boxing/unboxing of value types, crippling performance unnecessarily (if used for intensive workloads).

Comment: @Pop, I agree; but GetInt32(), for instance, probably do same thing internally

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the following generic extension method (that could be easily converted into a static helper function) to get possibly null values from a reader:

```
    public static T Get<T>(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        if (reader[columnName] == DbNull.Value)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)reader[columnName];
    }
```

Comment: that's going to box.
Can get a noticable perf hit when use it everywhere.

Comment: @Robert: To box is to encapsulate a value type inside an object, right? Can you explain why this function would box when called like Get<decimal?>(...) ?

Comment: @Robert:  I'm not sure that I understand why you feel this will cause boxing.  Unless I'm mistaken, neither implementation boxes and both have the same casting cost.

According to Reflector, the SqlDataReader stores it's values in an instance of the SqlBuffer class.  SqlBuffer has a property "Value" of type object in which it stores the database value by ordinal.  When a typed version of the value is requested, SqlBuffer performs a cast to the appropriate type.  

SqlDataReader's GetDecimal requests the value from SqlBuffer resulting in the same cast operation that BlueSam is using.

Comment: @Jesse, that is not what is happening. (And this is not just the case for SqlDatareader, but most implementations I have come across) The value is stored in a struct which can access most primitive types by reading them at the same field offset. GetInt32 will return this value as Int32. No boxing needed at all.

Comment: @Robert:  If I understand you correctly, you are saying that it is the GetValue method that will box to meet its object return type.  With due respect, would you please be so kind as to site your source?  My own investigations did not find this to be the case and I'm rather interested in seeing where I may have misinterpreted the decompilation.

Comment: @Jesse
Check out SqlBuffer.get_Value line 7c or 124 in decimal: It will return the appropriate data field as object, thus boxing it. OTOH, any ValueType value in an object reference had to be boxed to get there, so there wasn't any research needed to get to this conclusion. ;-)

Comment: @Robert:  I concede the point.  It appears that I erred by fixating on SqlBuffer's "Value" property being typed as object and did not track deeply enough to investigate that _value was typed as Storage.  Thanks for pushing me on this.  I just learned me something.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because the type `decimal` (a value type) and `null` (a reference value) don't play together.

Also, since you're assigning to the `Value` property of the `Nullable<decimal>` type, you're effectively attempting to assign `null` to a `decimal` type which, again, is a no-go.

You can explicitly make the `GetDecimal` result a nullable `decimal` type by casting it:

```
record.SaleAmount = sql.Reader.IsDBNull(IDX_SALEAMOUNT) ? 
    null : (decimal?)sql.Reader.GetDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT);
```

I would go with your second approach, though.

Comment: My only problem with approach two is it isnt totally evident to a JR programmer (people will have to maintain this after all); it actually takes a second to digest that we are only assigning when there is a value and just leaving it untouched otherwise. I know this seems trivial but trust me, people get confused over the simple stuff.

Comment: You have to weigh this against using casts and a ternary conditional operator, which I find to be at least as confusing. Just write the above code explicitly then, *or* add a comment that non-assignment means `null`.

Comment: which makes me think that Skeet's idea of an extension method may make the most sense since it would be most evident and readable. But I refuse to give him the check mark, he has too many points!

Comment: Well, there's a reason for that isn't there ;) Just go ahead =)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the Value property is readonly so you won't be able to assign to it anyway.

If you add a cast to the false part of the conditional to cast to nullable decimal the compiler should be happy. Try the following

```
record.SaleAmount = sql.Reader.IsDBNull(IDX_SALEAMOUNT) ? 
    null : (decimal?) sql.Reader.GetDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the null coalescing operator?

```
record.SaleAmount = (decimal?)sql.Reader.GetDecimal(IDX_SALEAMOUNT)
    ?? null;
```

Comment: `GetDecimal` returns `decimal`, which can never be `null`, thus `??` won't work.

Comment: I see you updated your post, but now it's worse. `?? null` is logically wrong (return value if it's not `null` and return `null` if it is `null`, which it never will be since `decimal` can't be `null`)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal.aspx

See the remarks section, it should throw an InvalidCastException if it is not actually a decimal

Answer (score 0):

To me, the cleanest solution is to remove it from the business logic tier altogether and just make the query return a non-null value to the reader in the first place

For example if using SQL Server..

```
SELECT IsNull(SalesAmount,0) ...
```

Comment: This depends wholly on what `NULL` and `0` actually mean! There's an important difference between "there is no sales amount available" and "the sales amount is 0.0"

Comment: But that would return `0`; he wants `null`.  Not `SqlDecimal.Null`, but `null` :)

Comment: I agree it would make for cleaner code but the others are right, someone can sell for zero and null means it hasnt sold.

Answer (score 0):

I use a FieldHelper class with Nullable<T> ToXXX(object) methods. Here's the
Decimal example (this was written during pre-Linq days - about 2-3 years ago, 
you're welcome to replace the delegate construct to Linq):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a nullable value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aValue">The value to be converted.</param>
/// <returns>The converted value.</returns>
public static Nullable<decimal> ToDecimal(object aValue)
{
   return ToNullable<decimal>(aValue,
     delegate(object aConvertableValue)
     {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(aConvertableValue);
     });
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the given value if necessary.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aValue">A value from the database.</param>
/// <param name="aConversion">A conversion delegate.</param>
/// <returns>null, or the given value.</returns>
private static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(
        object aValue, Converter<T> aConverter) where T : struct
{
  if (aValue == DBNull.Value || aValue == null)
     return null;
  else if (aValue is T)
     return (T)aValue;
  else
     return aConverter(aValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this this without paying too much in terms of runtime overhead, you can't be too picky, I'm afraid.

However, there's a more concise syntax:

```
public static Nullable<T> GetNullableValue<T>(this IDataRecord record, 
    int columnIndex, Func<int, T> getValue)
  where T: struct;
{
  if (record.IsDbNull(columnIndex))
    return null;
  else
    return getValue(columnIndex);
}

var xyz = reader.GetNullableValue(0, reader.GetDecimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

IsDbNull(int) is usually much slower that using methods like GetSqlInt32 and then comparing to DBNull.Value or using it's own .IsNull Like:

```
    public static int Int32(this SqlDataReader r, int ord)
    {
        var t = r.GetSqlInt32(ord);
        return t.IsNull ? default(int) : t.Value;
    }
```

Tried a few template solutions but to no avail so far. The problem is that all Sql-types (SqlInt32 here) types are actually structs and while they all have .Value property C# doesn't have real templates to handle that. Also they have their own INullable interface which has only .IsNull and is not conpatible with Nyllable<>.

I suspect that one would need full set of Sql-types as C# templates or to add ICOnvertible to them in order to be able to have just one or two templated methods.

If someone has maybe an idea with a functional trick or two speak up :-)